# Passenger thinks I'm on the wrong ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

weird issue. I have passenger installed on an Apache 2 server, and trying to get a Rails application running. First time deploying a rails application, so not really sure what's going on.

Passenger gives me this error:

[image]

But the problem is that 1.9.2-p136 isn't even installed on my system. I removed all ruby versions and completely reinstalled ruby with 1.9.3-p448. (I also have 2.0.0 but I default to 1.9.3)

Not seeing how passenger is even recognizing that I am running a build of ruby that doesnt exist on my system.

I'm hoping this is my last obstacle to getting this started. I have dealt with about every issue that I could have trying to get this damn rails app up. I'll tell you, they make up for how easy it is to develop with by making it impossible to deploy.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.9.2 is probably the system ruby (or was, at some point). Now, how in the heck Passenger is running on that while simultaneously using gems from an rvm install of 1.9.3...

Anyway, check your Passenger config. Make sure the `PassengerDefaultRuby` (if present) and `PassengerRuby` directives are pointing to the correct version; Passenger often gets confused by varying PATHs, and this is especially true with rvm where you may be running a different version in your user shell session than system tools will find on their own.

There's a reason people like solutions like Unicorn, Puma, and Rainbows. ;) Passenger, once you get it compiled and configured, is pretty much fire and forget, but getting to that point can be painful.

Comment: The reason why Unicorn/Puma/Rainbows don't have this problem is because they use the PATH from your shell (assuming you start it through your shell), while Apache and Nginx (being started from init) don't have the same environment variables. But if that's your biggest issue, then you can just use Passenger Standalone. You start it with `passenger start`, it uses the exact same environment as your shell, and pretty much just works. You can even put it behind an Nginx reverse proxy just like you do with Unicorn/Puma/Rainbows.

Comment: So the point is: use Passenger Standalone if you can't get Apache/Nginx working correctly. But on the Apache/Nginx side, we've already made major improvements in Phusion Passenger 4.0 by inferring the environment variables form your shell config files.

Comment: I actually just removed the PassengerRuby directive and it worked. Not sure what the hell the problem was, but its working, so im not going to complain!